# Assign multiple values to an object in one go as with variable assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

It is possible to do:

```
let a = 1,
    b = 3,
    c = 9;
```

Is it also possible to do:

```
obj.a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;
```

This is still very readable, but a lot less typing, then writing `obj` a lot of times.

Comment: declaration happens way earlier, i need to assignment only

Comment: you could jump into your delorean and use [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) ... but that's not recommended

Comment: `Object.assign(obj, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });` would do it in 1 line, but just assigning 3 times in a row is not a bad thing

Comment: less typing is arguably one of those early programmer goals. Experienced programmers choose readability and editability over tersness. As proof see pretty much any major company's style guide which would tell you not to code this way.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are already defined, you can use shorthand property names to define the object in one go, without any repetition:

```
const obj = { a, b, c };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the defined variables using shorthand property names

```js
let a = 1,
    b = 3,
    c = 9;

let  obj = {a,b,c}
    
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: this is the best so far. although double memory usage but very easy to follow

Comment: `double memory usage` huh?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer in most cases memory useage will not be an issue as JS uses grabage collector

Comment: true. this what i'm doing right now too. so it's good to see it's being recommended. only problem i see is i'm declaring/assigning 2x variables for same amount of data. but not a big or even medium problem.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a relation between the property names and the values then one can write a compact object definition using `map`. Otherwise one can just initialize the object with names and values.

```js
// function
var obj = {};
['a', 'b', 'c'].map((x, i) => (obj[x] = i));
console.log(obj);

// no function
var obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 4};
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are not already assigned, you could use `Object.assign`:

```js
const obj = Object.assign({}, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
console.log(obj);
```

Otherwise, use ES6 shorthand property notation:

```js
const [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3];
const obj = { a, b, c };
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (if object is re-assignable ex: `let` NOT `const` ):

```
obj = {...obj, a : 1,
    b : 2,
    c: 3,
}
```

Thank you :)